# Apache poi replace existing picture on header

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

Is there any way to replace an image on word(docx) file header by name of the image with apache poi? I'am thinking about that:

> +--------------------------------+
>   +HEADER myimage.jpeg-+
>   + -----------BODY------------+
>   +--------------------------------+
>
> replaceImage("myimage.jpeg", newPictureInputStream,
>   "newPicture_name.jpeg");

Here what I tried:

```
    XWPFParagraph originalParagraph = null;
    originalParagraph = getPictureParagraphInHead(lookingPictureName);
    ListIterator<XWPFRun> it = originalParagraph.getRuns().listIterator();
    XWPFRun replacedRun = null;

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        XWPFRun run = it.next();
        int runIDX = it.nextIndex();
        if (run.getEmbeddedPictures().size() > 0) {
            XWPFRun newRun = null;
            newRun = new XWPFRun(run.getCTR(), (IRunBody) originalParagraph);
            originalParagraph.addRun(newRun);
            originalParagraph.removeRun(originalParagraph.getRuns().indexOf(run));
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Write some code which loops over the text in the file, looking for your magic placeholder, then grab the contents and write the image?

Comment: Any other forward-looking post?

Comment: So after some hours I do not recommend this API (Apache POI). It has generated corrupted file. I used only framework methods. I saw the POI source code and I freaked out. Do not use this framework or good luck.

Comment: Make sure you're using the latest version of Apache POI. Shouldn't be any issues with corrupted Word documents from XWPF!

Comment: I used 3.17. It is the latest version according to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can get the "filename" of the image with POI. It's probably in the XML so you might have to make your own method for finding the image.

To get the Header you do:

```
XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy policy = new XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(doc); // XWPFDocument
XWPFHeader header = policy.getDefaultHeader();
```

And to delete the images, get the XWPFRun from your paragraph (cell/row/table..)

```
CTR ctr = myRun.getCTR(); // 
List<CTDrawing> images = ctr.getDrawingList();
for (int i=0; i<images.size(); i++)
{
    ctr.removeDrawing(i);
}
```